# Parsing maths expression

Tags: python, parsing, operators, python-3.4

So the following code with the function: "eqn" converts a string: "d" that is a mathematical expression, into a list of its integers and operators according to Reverse Polish Notation, where "add", "subtract", "multiply" and "divide" represent +, -, * and / respectively. There is also the "negate" operator which takes any positive integer and turns it into a negative integer. Example inputs and outputs:

- eqn("10 5 add") should produce an output of [10, 5 and "add"]
- eqn("5 6 add 2 negate divide") should produce an output of [5, 6, "add", -2, "divide"]

With the negative function though, if it is not used correctly (not after a number) then the function should return the index number of the first incorrect "negate".

For example:

- eqn("negate 2 add 2") should produce an output of 0
- eqn("2 4 add negate") should produce an output of 3

  ```
  def eqn(d):
   extrac = []

  for e in eqnStr.split():
   if len(e) == 0:
      continue

   try:
      extrac.append(int(e))
      continue
   except ValueError:
      pass

   try:
      extrac.append(float(e))
      continue
   except ValueError:
      pass

  extrac.append(e)

  return extrac
  ```

The problem is that the negate function won't work. Instead of changing the integer to a negative it just comes out as "negate" in the output when essentially it should 'disappear'. For example:

eqn("5 6 add 2 negate divide") should produce an output of [5, 6, "add", -2, "divide"] but instead produces [5, 6, "add", 2, "negate", "divide"] How do I fix this and how do I get it to show the index number of the first invalid negate?

Comment: 2 4 add negate -> becomes 3?

Comment: @ergonaut Yes because the negate is after another operator and 3 is the index of the negate

Comment: Seems to me there is some discrepancy in your `negate`

Comment: You'll need to explain this step by step.  This is clearly not how RPN works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a special case to handle negate. Try something like this:

```
def eqn(d):
    extrac = []

    for e in d.split():
        if len(e) == 0:
            continue

        try:
            extrac.append(int(e))
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            extrac.append(float(e))
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass

        if e == 'negate':
            if isinstance(extrac[-1], str):
                return len(extrac)
            else:
                extrac[-1] *= -1
                continue

        extrac.append(e)

    return extrac
```

Output:

```
   eqn("2 4 add negate")
=> 3
   eqn("5 6 add 2 negate divide")
=> [5, 6, 'add', -2, 'divide']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong approach to RPN, which should involve pushing and popping operands onto and off of a stack while parsing a list.

For example, `eqn([1, 2, 3, '+', '*'])` would perform `(3 + 2) * 1`. The builtin python 'list' type supports appending (pushing) and popping.

More on RPN here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation